# How to enable ckanext-scheming extension in CKAN

Tags: ckan

I am trying to have a custom form for Datasets in CKAN.

I have installed ckanext-scheming extension and added the scheming plugin to the plugins like this:

```
ckan.plugins = activity scheming_datasets
```

I have also set the following:

```
scheming.dataset_schemas = ckanext.scheming:subfields.yaml
scheming.presets = ckanext.scheming:presets.json
scheming.dataset_fallback = false
```

I expected to see a new UI when going to the Dataset definition form (e.g., Add Dataset), but still don't see any change in the UI of defining datasets in CKAN.

I also cleared the browser cache and restarted CKAN but no success.

Comment: same issue I'm getting right now
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/discussions/7721

Comment: So, @VivekKumar, please vote up my question maybe other experts would notice our problem then.

Comment: Sure, we can collaborate on this problem. I've been debugging this scene for the past week. We can share our work, and when we see each other's approach, maybe we can find something. How can we connect?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by changing the `CKAN` version from `2.9.8` to `2.10.0`, and my `ckanext-scheming` version is `3.0.0`

Comment: can you solve this issue??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76825158/error-while-configuring-ckan-fluent-with-ckanext-scheming